# Add actual date to PDF Textfield

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm using the iText7 library. My goal is to add a PdfTextFormField "ActDate" and a button to an existing PDF-File.
If I press the button, I want to enter the actual date into the TextField.

How can this be done?
Is it also possible to add the Windows user to another textfield?

Thanks a lot for aour help!! :-)
Eric

FYI: I can define the PDF Viewer, with which the Document will be opended (Acrobat Reader DC)

```
....
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(destPdf, true);
PdfTextFormField dateField = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(destPdf, new Rectangle(50, 70, 60, 8), "Id_Date", "dd.mm.yyy");
PdfButtonFormField button = PdfFormField.CreatePushButton(destPdf, new Rectangle(30, 70, 8, 8), "Id_BtnOK", "OK");

PdfAction date = PdfAction.CreateJavaScript("AFDate_FormatEx(\"yyyy-mm-dd\");");
button.SetAction(date); /// ??????? How to set the Date into the "dateField" ????

form.AddField(dateField);
form.AddField(button);
....
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some snippets of your code.

Comment: Unless you have control over the PDF viewer that your PDF recipients are going to use, **this isn't worth doing**. You can certainly use iText to add the field, the button, and the appropriate JavaScript to insert the current date into the text field when the PDF is viewed. However, the likelihood of a recipient opening the PDF in a viewer capable of properly executing the script is very low. Do you have control over the viewer being used by your recipients?